# package com.avaya.sce.runtime does not exist how to fix

Tags: maven, pom.xml, ivr, orchestration

Hello I was wondering how to fix a  "package com.avaya.sce.runtime does not exist" when I try to do a maven build of a Orchestration designer project

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this error too and after editing some necessary parts i didn't get it